# How to import contentversion records(csv file) using dataloader

Tags: data-loader, content, contentversion, contentdocumentlink

i have three records in csv file and three pdf files. how can i import these content version records to sandbox. i tried, but when i am uploading csv file using dataloader, i got **Required fields are missing: [VersionData]** error.

Comment: You need to give path of your attachment in VersionData field

Comment: @salesforceDeveloper Please consider turning your comment into an answer so that other people can see that this question has been successfully answered, and try this themselves if they're experiencing a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the path of your attachment in VersionData field of ContentVersion Object.